# Ubuntu 16.04 Steam Crashes on start

Tags: 16.04, steam, crash

When I run steam the icon appears for around 5 seconds then disappears. I have already uninstalled and reinstalled steam several times but the problem persists.

```
jp@JP-PC:~$ steam &
[1] 13570
jp@JP-PC:~$ Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
libGL error: unable to load driver: radeonsi_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: radeonsi
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

Comment: Can you run `steam` from the terminal and paste the error messages in your post?

Comment: @edwinksl done.

Answer (score 1):

Just enter this command on your terminal:

```
LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6' DISPLAY=:0 steam
```